# Removing disks and replacing them with one large

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2

Over the years my Ubuntu has grown into a rats nest with not less than 5 disks and the disk my system sits on is full. Now I want to clean up and have bought a larger disk to which I cloned my system disk. Unfortunately grub sits on one of the other disks and boot-repair refuses to move grub to my new disk. 
What can I do besides a complete new installation?
Thanks in advance for any tip.
H

Comment: You cannot clone & keep old drive. You then have duplicate UUIDs. You can change all the references to UUID or just do a new install & restore from your backup. Good way to confirm your backup is good as if something is missing you still have old drive. Post link to summary report from Boot-Repair. It should show duplicate UUID, but may be some other issue.

Comment: Thanks,but the old drive is removed.